# A theorem about three lines, any two of them being coplanar

Tags: geometry

I am pretty convinced the following result holds in dimension 3:

> If three non-coplanar lines are such that any two of them are coplanar, then
>   either all three lines are parallel, or they all intersect at the same point.

But I failed to come with a demonstration. Note that this is not homework as I need this in a problem of physics whose solution I highlighted on the stackexchange for physics, in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/331373/154997) (the part until QED).

Comment: Call the lines "a", "b", and "c".  Since a and b are coplanar, they either intersect or are parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g_1$, $g_2$, $g_3$ are not pairwise parallel two of them have to intersect. Assume that  $g_1\wedge g_2=P$. As $P\in g_1\subset g_1\vee g_3$, and similarly $P\in g_2\vee g_3$ it follows that $(g_1\vee g_3)\cap (g_2\vee g_3)\ne\emptyset$. In fact $(g_1\vee g_3)\cap (g_2\vee g_3)=g_3$, which then implies $P\in g_3$.

Comment: I see, the intersection is exactly $g_3$ because of the assumptions they are not all coplanar. I feel stupid: this was trivial! Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how the last step is more obvious than the fact we want to prove at all. If distributed, the final intersection equals $$\underbrace{(g_1\cap g_2)}_P\cup(g_3\cap g_2)\cup(g_1\cap g_3)\cup\underbrace{(g_3 \cap g_3)}_{g_3}.$$
So I do not would say that the intersection is *obviously* $g_3$, but some superset of $g_3\cup\{P\}$ which does not allow the conclusion $P\in g_3$ but (at most) $P\in g_3\cup\{P\}$ which is trivial but not helpful.

Comment: @M.Winter: The intersection of two planes is empty or a line, namely the only common line of the two planes.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Could it be that $g_1\vee g_2$ means a plane? If so, I was not aware of this notation.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept that this picture shows all ways in which three planes can intersect, then I have some elementar reasoning for you.

[image]

Lets call the lines $a,b$ and $c$. Any two of theme define a plane (they are coplanar). Call the planes $E_{ab},E_{bc}$ and $E_{ca}$. So any two of these planes intersect in a common line, e.g. $E_{ab}$ and $E_{bc}$ intersect in $b$. This excludes two of the five pictures above (the first and the third). In the second picture all lines are coplanar (actually even idnetical), hence we have to exclude it too.

In the two remaining ones, either all (intersection-)lines are parallel (fourth pic) or intersect in a common point (last pic).

Comment: Thanks for the work you have put into this but I do not find it that easy to convince myself those are the only possibilities. Generally useful once achieved though!

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis I think to check that these are all possibilities it comes down to study the sets of solutions to the linear equiations given by three planes. I (maybe) can extend my answer if you think this would help.

Comment: Yes, true, I see what you mean. Actually, this could make an interesting question (a new different question I mean) which has not been asked before as far as I can tell. That would be make your answer more visible.